# Can't save meta field value if the title not set

Tags: custom-field, metabox, post-meta

I'm using the example from WordPress Codex (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box#Procedural)  to add and save meta box values. Unfortunately I can't save the value of the meta field when the title of the post is empty. Is it the normal functionality or I missed something?

```
    <?php

/**
 * Adds a box to the main column on the Post and Page edit screens.
 */
function myplugin_add_meta_box() {

    $screens = array( 'post', 'page' );

    foreach ( $screens as $screen ) {

        add_meta_box(
            'myplugin_sectionid',
            __( 'My Post Section Title', 'myplugin_textdomain' ),
            'myplugin_meta_box_callback',
            $screen
        );
    }
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'myplugin_add_meta_box' );

/**
 * Prints the box content.
 * 
 * @param WP_Post $post The object for the current post/page.
 */
function myplugin_meta_box_callback( $post ) {

    // Add a nonce field so we can check for it later.
    wp_nonce_field( 'myplugin_save_meta_box_data', 'myplugin_meta_box_nonce' );

    /*
     * Use get_post_meta() to retrieve an existing value
     * from the database and use the value for the form.
     */
    $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_my_meta_value_key', true );

    echo '<label for="myplugin_new_field">';
    _e( 'Description for this field', 'myplugin_textdomain' );
    echo '</label> ';
    echo '<input type="text" id="myplugin_new_field" name="myplugin_new_field" value="' . esc_attr( $value ) . '" size="25" />';
}

/**
 * When the post is saved, saves our custom data.
 *
 * @param int $post_id The ID of the post being saved.
 */
function myplugin_save_meta_box_data( $post_id ) {

    /*
     * We need to verify this came from our screen and with proper authorization,
     * because the save_post action can be triggered at other times.
     */

    // Check if our nonce is set.
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['myplugin_meta_box_nonce'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Verify that the nonce is valid.
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['myplugin_meta_box_nonce'], 'myplugin_save_meta_box_data' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // If this is an autosave, our form has not been submitted, so we don't want to do anything.
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return;
    }

    // Check the user's permissions.
    if ( isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) && 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {

        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
            return;
        }

    } else {

        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
            return;
        }
    }

    /* OK, it's safe for us to save the data now. */

    // Make sure that it is set.
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['myplugin_new_field'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Sanitize user input.
    $my_data = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['myplugin_new_field'] );

    // Update the meta field in the database.
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_my_meta_value_key', $my_data );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'myplugin_save_meta_box_data' );
```

Comment: The title of what? Please explain the problem in more detail and add any relevant code to the question.

Comment: I edited my question. The title of the post.

Comment: How is it hooked? The function trails off at the end.

Comment: I used the full example from codex, please see the updated comment.

Comment: The myplugin_save_meta_box_data() doesn't run if the TITLE is empty.

Comment: I don't see any major problems with that code (other than some nitpicky optimization issues). To answer your question, no a post does NOT need to have a title in order for meta to save since posts are referenced by id throughout core, not by name (or even slug). I'm not sure why you'd be having that problem. I would check your error log or run a debug trace to find out what might be happening. You can also look at the db directly to see if the problem is SAVING or FETCHING the metadata. Also try disabling your other plugins, just in case.

Comment: For test I checked other themes with custom meta boxes, they don't save the post until the TITLE of the post is empty. It looks like it's the normal functionality.